# YouMax video upload date

Tags: jquery-plugins, youtube-api

I've been using the YouMax plugin which enables you to embed your YouTube channel on your website. However, I am having problems as it displays the uploaded date in months and years. I'd like it to display days, weeks, months and years.

You can view the source code here http://jsfiddle.net/wCKKU/

I believe that its this that needs adjusting to make it calculate in day, weeks, months and years.

```
function getDateDiff(timestamp) {
if (null == timestamp || timestamp == "" || timestamp == "undefined") return "?";
var splitDate = ((timestamp.toString().split('T'))[0]).split('-');
var d1 = new Date();
var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
var d2Y = parseInt(splitDate[0], 10);
var d1M = d1.getMonth();
var d2M = parseInt(splitDate[1], 10);
var diffInMonths = (d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2M + 12 * d2Y);
if (diffInMonths <= 1) return "1 month";
else if (diffInMonths < 12) return diffInMonths + " months";
var diffInYears = Math.floor(diffInMonths / 12);
if (diffInYears <= 1) return "1 year";
else if (diffInYears < 12) return diffInYears + " years"
}
```

Comment: Youmax Lite is the latest version of this plugin. http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax/lite.html This already has the date in the format "23 March 2015"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the plugin by a small block of code in the middle of the function:

```
var d2M = parseInt(splitDate[1], 10); // this line is already there
var d1D = d1.getDate();
var d2D = parseInt(splitDate[2],10);
var diffInDays = (d1D + 30 *d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2D + 30 *d2M + 12 *d2Y);
if (diffInDays < 2) return "1 day";
else if (diffInDays < 7) return diffInDays+" days";
else if (diffInDays > 7 && diffInDays < 14) return "1 week";
else if (diffInDays > 14 && diffInDays < 30) return Math.floor(diffInDays / 7) + " weeks";
var diffInMonths = (d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2M + 12 * d2Y); // this line is already there
```

Note that this isn't a particularly elegant way to handle the issue, but it matches the coding style the plugin is already using, and at least won't break anything else.

Also, as a side comment, if you're modifying the plugin code you'll want to fix a bug in it at the same time. Getting the current month should look like this:

```
var d1M = d1.getMonth() + 1;
```

This is because in Javascript, the getMonth() function returns the month on a zero-based index, and your math won't be reliable unless you switch it to a one-based index.

Comment: your code almost worked, i did also use a fix but the video upload date is out by 10 days causing it show a negative number.

Comment: You could then change if (diffInDays < 7) return diffInDays+" days"; to if (diffInDays < 2) return "1 day"; if (diffInDays < 7) return diffInDays+" days"; (I edited the answer to reflect that). Again, that'll match the pattern of what the plugin already is doing. But I guess I'm a bit confused as to what you're really wanting from this plugin if you're displaying dates on videos that have a future upload date. I assumed you wanted it to show how many days ago something was uploaded, no? If you're working with future dates a lot, you could just run the final difference through the abs() method

Comment: sry for not being very clear, i want it to show how many days ago a video was uploaded. the new code was still showing wrong dates

Comment: That's what I thought. So if you go with the edited code above, then it will show "1 day" for those 1 day or less (including the future dates), the number of days plus the word "days" if it is less than 7, then the number of weeks up to a month (generically assuming 30 days in a month, since this is plugin is all about estimating, anyway), and so on. If you have a timestamp that isn't showing the right time diff now, you can post it.

Comment: yh the new code stops showing negative numbers but the wrong upload date, also between a video that say 6 day and the other 1 week the one in the middle say 1 month http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/7809/292t.jpg

Comment: Shoot--TOTALLY my fault. Rather than using getDay(), it needs to be getDate() -- the first returns the day of the week, the second returns the day of the month (which is what the math will be based on). I've edited the code above a second time; sorry for the brain fart! give it a try to see if it works. (note that just adding 10 to the day won't be a consistent fix; it may sort of estimate what you want, given that you don't need exact dates past the first week, but you may run into a couple of trouble dates here and there). Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/pumxE/

Comment: Oh an over sight on both of us and you was right about the +10 it cause problems in other places

Comment: ok its working now without any problem selected this as my answer ;)